pygame.mixer не воспроизводит большое количество звуков
В моей игре при выстреле воспроизводится звук. Если стрелять часто, то новые звуки перестают воспроизводиться(даже если это не звуки выстрелов). Для воспроизведения звука использую pygame.mixer, класс звука инициализирую в начале кода и в нужный момент проигрываю функцией play().
Вот демонстрация:
https://youtu.be/_gLGjK3QyNw
Код:(учился программировать на этом проекте, поэтому старый код полон костылей и практически нечитаем. Если что, звук выстрела инициализируется в 23 строке файла bullet.py, воспроизводится строкой ниже(при появлении/инициализации пули))
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VW-kwjzIVpQysiDZ4O4M9bPedhJvg9-y/view?usp=sharing
(Да, я делаю танчики сорокалетней давности)
